# Fluid Simulation - fluid quantity

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I am working with Fluid Simulation, and I am struggling with some of the settings. I read through the manual on blender.org but I haven't found a solution for this.

I am trying to add fluid in a "container" (in the screenshot it's a pipe, but the same problem happens with any kind of container).

Even though the emitter object is set on inflow, the fluid doesn't fill the whole container, but it stops as soon as it reaches the emitter itself. I took some screenshot as example.

Screenshot1:
[image: fluid simulation fail]

As you can see here the fluid reaches the emitter but it doesn't go up the pipe. I ran a simulation for about 300 frames, nothing changed. Fluid gets to that level and stays there till the end.

Screenshot2:
[image]

I moved the emitter to the top of the pipe, and with exactly the same settings the fluid now fills the pipe and gets till a level where it reaches the emitter, but again, it doesn't grow more than that.

Do you know why this is happening? How can I solve this problem?

Many thanks to whoever has time to help me out :)

Comment: It looks like it's a known problem and it has probably not been fixed: https://developer.blender.org/T77827

Comment: That is so sad :-/ there's so many instances where this could be useful. Is there any way around this problem? I thought about playing with gravity, but because I have to fill a pipe with an irregular shape, I will not be able to make the water go through the whole pipe.

Comment: Can't you move the inflow object up?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the inflow stopping to emit water when it's submerged is a known problem, see [here](https://developer.blender.org/T77827), so it has probably not been fixed yet.